# Add sliding transition for infinite scroll from last slide to first slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js to create slides which are auto-scrolling at 5 seconds each. I have got the infinite scroll, but I haven't been able to add the sliding transition from the last slide to the first slide - It just sort of appears.

You can see the issue here - https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/spotify-circle-animation/#projects

I think I am missing something, I am not sure what it may be.

jQuery:

```
var indexSlide = 0, sliding = true;    
$('#fullpage').fullpage({

                anchors: ['home','about','projects','contact'],

                loopHorizontal: true,

                fixedElements: '#toggle,#overlay',

                slidesNavigation: true,

                menu: '#menu',

                controlArrows: false,

                slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',

                afterLoad : function(anchorLink, index, direction) {


                    if((index === 3 || anchorLink === 'projects')) {
                        callMakeDiv('#1f3264', 3);
                        $('#slide1 .card').addClass('come-in').one(animationEnd,function (){
                            $('.card').css('opacity','1');
                        });

                        if(sliding){
                            var id = setInterval(function(){
                                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
                                indexSlide++;
                            },5000);
                        }
                    } 
                },

                onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex) {
                    var isFirst = direction === 'right' && nextSlideIndex > slideIndex + 1;
                    var isLast = direction === 'left' && slideIndex > nextSlideIndex + 1;
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass('no_transition', isFirst || isLast);
            }
 });
```

css:

```
.no_transition {
    transition: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the option `continuousHorizontal:true` of fullPage.js but it requires you to use the [Continuous Horizontal Extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/continuous-horizontal.html).

Comment: I have almost implemented it. If you could just point me out to the right direction - only the transistion is left and I can't figure that out.